# Bitmap Style Designer: different font colors for different button state

Tags: inno-setup, window-style

I want to create custom window vsf style for my Inno Setup installer, where I need to change buttons font color depending on its state: focused, clicked or hovered.
Is it possible by customizing style in embarcadero Bitmap Style Designer?

I've tried to use TseTextObject as a Button:

[image]

But have no luck, as text on the button seems independed:

[image: With TseTextObject as a Button]
[image: Without button style]

TseTextObject as a Button and Without button style

Comment: Maybe this is coincidence but are you talking about (my product :) Graphical Installer which has exactly this feature? It is possible to set button colors for different states for Inno Setup installer (check http://www.graphical-installer.com).  If yes than this cannot be set in Object Inspector but directly in installer script.

Comment: So what are you using?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, sorry, I ment I'm using **only** vcl styles inno.

Comment: OK, but I still do not understand the problem. You screenshot shows different text color for different states.